customer to employee loan
A customer offered to make me a loan, he leaves and comes back with the money and had also told me he was going to draw up the paperwork.
Before he comes to hand me the money he stopped and asked my G.M. what his thoughts were, and my G.M. told him about a loan that took a little longer to pay back made by the owners of the business that was bought by another company in which we worked and still work for.
Is this a privilege he is allowed to divulge? For clarification, we worked for a company together for about 5 years where he was my G.M. and another company recently acquired our business, and we both still work for the new company. The loan information he gave the customer was from the old business.

what business are you in where a customer offers you a loan?

I can't make sense of this story, it's very unclear how the GM or the business are related to this scenario at all. It sounds like you are describing an offer of a personal loan between two individuals, one of which who happens to be a customer at the other's place of employment - what does the GM have to do with anything? Why would the GM be prohibited from mentioning the terms of a completely unrelated business arrangement?

correct, i deal poker, a regular at the card house offered to make me a loan. he decided to ask my gm who told him about a previous loan with the owners of the previous business. he knew about that issue because the owners would send him messages to ask about the money.

let me add, i didnt ask nor did i even know this reg had that kind of money to loan out. i would never ask a customer, it kind of randomly came up as things do at a poker table.

Why do you care if your manager talked to a customer about something unrelated to your job? If you're trying to pick a fight, I suggest that's a bad idea.

Both the loan and the poker being tied closely to your business seem like a problem, to be honest. That the GM is giving out information on this is just a symptom of the bad situation.

it bothers me because he is talking to them as my boss about my finances, which ultimately made the customer change their mind. and i agree about the bad situation, yet i feel like too much information was shared without my consent...

Have you though about taking a job where you don't have to take out loans regularly?

This individual only represents the company in their official duties, and not necessarily, under the same obligations the company is under. Whether or not the company was under agreement not to disclose your loan would be in the paperwork for the loan itself. It also depends how this individual knew this information, if he was aware of the loan, because you shared the information then he was under no obligation to keep it to themselves except out of a personal obligation surrounding your relationship with them.

This is a catastrophically bad idea and I am a little shocked that your general manager didn't shoot this idea down immediately.
It is a bad enough idea in general for an employee to take a loan from a customer of the business that employs him.  There is far too much opportunity for drama or misunderstandings at work if the lender wants to come in to the business to ask about a loan or the borrower wants to avoid the lender while he's at work.
In your specific case where the borrower is a poker dealer and the lender is a poker player, though, this is a terrible conflict of interest.  If the player comes in and wins a bunch of money fairly on a table you're dealing, every other player is likely to question whether they lost money because you're colluding with the player to whom you owe money.  If the player gets a favorable ruling from the dealer, there will be similar questions about whether the dealer is biased.  I can't imagine a manager allowing an employee to create that sort of conflict of interest and I can't imagine a gaming regulator that would be happy to have to deal with that sort of conflict of interest.

Yeah this sounds very bribe adjacent.


Is a privilege he is allowed to divulge?

Yes, if he was asked on a personal level whether he thinks you're a good loan risk or not. The details may be confidential but the fact that people have to chase you for their money isn't.
Especially in gambling circles where addiction is a well recognised problem.

no one ever had to chase me down i had made multipleloans with the original owners  last one just took a little longer than expected, and was paid in full. that was the only time i was late to pay any debt i have accumulated. and i'm well aware it sounds crazy but anyone in the poker world knows this happens all the time, and it can go either way. but thats also why you dont just loan anyone money. idk im just trying to determine if my boss was out of line by telling the player an isolated instance instead of taking a neutral "at your own risk" stance

alsio i make anywhere from 500-1k loans every week and pay them exactly when i say.

Your boss could have fired you for soliciting money from a client. The idea of a gambling establishment is for all the clients money to end up with the business. I'm aware of how things work. It's a ruthless industry. Needing loans weekly in the gambling industry is a potential sign of addiction. I'm not advising you to change, it doesn't seem you're hurting anyone else, and it's your life, ducking and diving and rationalisations is part of the territory.

You allowed your personal finances to become part of the workplace, and it seems based on your comments it isn't the first time.  There are no HIPAA-style protections about the personal stuff you do at work, everybody can talk about it all they want with whomever they want.

HIPAA is only for health related information, might want to reword your statement, to simply say there are no protections for this type of information. So of course HIPAA would not apply to personal loans
